# getting the name of a class through an instance of that class

Tags: actionscript-3, classname

I have a function that takes as parameters 2 instances of a (custom) class. But they can each be one of several classes, and I need to then call another function based on what type they are. I'd like to do something like this:

```
function any_any(inst1, inst2) {
    this[inst1.classname + "_" + inst2.classname] (inst1, inst2);
}
function Circle_Line(circle:Circle, line:Line) {
    //treat this case
}
```

Should I go and define 'classname' in each of my classes, or is there a better way to get the class name of an instance?
I don't know how to get typeof() to return anything other than 'object' for a custom class, maybe it's possible?

EDIT: It would be inconvenient to use the instanceof operator, as each class can be 1 of 6 (currently).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [instanceof](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary389.html), or [the 'is' operator](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/operators.html#is), or the [getQualifiedClassName method](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package.html#getQualifiedClassName())

Answer (score 0):

You can use `instanceof`

```
   var a:Number;

   if (a instanceof Number)
   {
       trace("a is a number");
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

another way to get the class of an instance is using

```
var c:Class = instance["constructor"];
```

then you can do something like this:

```
switch(c)
{
    case Circle:
        whatever();
}
```

Comment: This want work if you replace Circle with Object, how ever it should.